# MySQL all results from main table and some results from left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One with images related to an article number. And one with article numbers on an photos

What I want to do is to list all images (navn) from the first table that is a specific article number (art_id) and max 5 images from the second table where the article number (artid) appears on photos (fotostation).

I'm not able to wrap my head around how to do this at the moment :)

This doesn't work

```
SELECT i.* FROM ecs_article_images AS i 
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT * FROM ecs_article_images_inneholder WHERE art_id = i.art_id LIMIT 0,5 ORDER BY dato DESC) AS inn ON inn.fotostation=i.fotostation                          
 WHERE i.art_id='MS174868' ORDER BY  nr, id DESC
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `ecs_article_images` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `navn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `nr` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `art_id` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `fotostation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `dato` datetime NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `ecs_article_images_inneholder` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fotostation` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `artid` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `dato` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The tables are related with the fotostation field. To find the name of a file having a artid in "ecs_article_images_inneholder" i must lookup navn in "ecs_article_images" with the same fotostation.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  In particular, it is unclear how the two tables are related -- by article, by foto station, or both.

Comment: I've tried adding a description of the relationship

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows.  I'm not sure how the two tables are related.  The following assumes that it is on both the article and foto station:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM ecs_article_images i LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT inn.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inn.art_id, inn.fotostation ORDER BY dato DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ecs_article_images_inneholder inn
      WHERE  LIMIT 0,5 ORDER BY dato DESC) AS inn ON  
     ) inn
     ON inn.art_id = i.art_id AND
        inn.fotostation = i.fotostation AND
        inn.seqnum <= 5                      
 WHERE i.art_id = 'MS174868'
 ORDER BY  nr, id DESC;
```

The key is that the `PARTITION BY` keys need to match the `JOIN` keys.

Comment: I'm not able to run this SQL, get this error: "Something is wrong in your syntax nær '(PARTITION BY inn.art_id, inn.fotostation ORDER BY dato DESC) as seqnum"

Comment: @johnohod . . . This requires MySQL 8.0 -- which has been out for several years.